# Symfony overwrite controller and action

Tags: php, symfony

I use HWIO bundle and after my custom service throws in ConnectController in public function `connectServiceAction(Request $request, $service)` in this action throws me to HWIO template, I know how to reload template but I don't need another template I need stay from rout: example I have route "home_page" after social connect I want still rout "home_page"

This is my service:

```
class UserProvider implements OAuthAwareUserProviderInterface
{
    protected $grabProject;

    public function __construct(GgrabGithubProject $grabProject)
    {
        $this->grabProject = $grabProject;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $serviceProvider = $service."Provider";

        $user = $this->$serviceProvider->setUserData($user, $response);
        $grabProject = $this->grabProject->grabProject($response->getAccessToken(), $user);
    }
}
```

In my bundle I add

```
class MyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'HWIOAuthBundle';
    }
}
```

and copy ConnectController in my directory and change logic instead render template I add redirest to to roting to "home_page" but if I need overwrite controller another Bundle, what to do then ?

```
class MyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'HWIOAuthBundle';//how to add another bundle ? 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`HWIOAuthBundle` does not have a `ConnectController` defined as a service, so you basically need to redeclare the routing where `ConnectController` is hard coded:

1. https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing/login.xml
2. https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml
3. https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml

An example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="hwi_oauth_connect" path="/">
        <default key="_controller">YourCustomBundle:Connect:connect</default>
    </route>
</routes>
```